# How to avoid sqlite database being overwritten by other party

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, sqlite

I am working on an app which is meant to handle requests between two or more parties. These requests are stored in an sqlite file on a server. When any of the parties wants to check if they received any request they simply download the database and filter out the requests which are meant for them. This part is working fine.

However, when it comes to sending a request and upload the modified sqlite file I get a bit confused as I havent done this before. How can I avoid multiple parties trying to update the database at the exact same time and overwriting each-other's updates?

I am not after source code examples, rather just ideas from anyone who has done something similar before.

Thank you

Comment: Ugh. It doesn't get any worse than transferring the whole database back and forth. Are you sure you want to follow this path?

Comment: Leaving this as a comment, not an answer, since I don't want any points or upvotes for suggesting my company's product. Having said that, Zumero (I won't even link it) is made to solve *exactly* this sort of problem, with little or no modifications to the client-side SQLite code. It handles syncs, merges, simultaneous updates, etc.

Comment: That Zumero looks really cool. I am going to try it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple users shouldn't update a database on the server by downloading it, modifying it and then sending it back up (and overwriting it).  This is slow and obviously has concurrency issues.

You should look at putting a front end app server in front of the database.  Something like a SOAP web service or restful http server.  Some webApi server options: [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) + [express](http://expressjs.com/), [Asp.net webapi](http://www.asp.net/web-api), [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) + [Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)- many others out there.

Comment: Thank you. That is a lot of help. I am novice-level but really enjoy programming.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is ideal in an embedded environment. You can tie the database directly to the application for settings etc. Once you start with a more traditional client/server architecture like the one you're going for, SQLite might not be the ideal solution. I can see two options:

- Abstract the calls to the database so that updates happen in a proper way, through SQL calls on the database and not by replacing the database file. This can easily be done by building import/export functionality. You don't want to be transferring the entire database all the time, since that defeats the purpose of having a database in the first place.
- Use an actual SQL server like MySQL and use that to connect from your client applications. You still want to add some kind of layer in between however, since making an SQL server accessible to the entire Internet is a bad idea. If this is an intranet application, you should be fine.

Johan.

Comment: Johan, thank you for your answer. Its a shame I can only accept one answer because yours is as useful as bryanmac's answer.

Comment: Yeah, think both Bryanmac and I posted at the same time. No worries, glad it worked out for you.